# Why getting error 24: too may file descriptor opened in asm

Tags: linux, x86-64, nasm, calling-convention

question *number1:*

Having this nasm:

```
section .data
dat db "write out this:%x", 0xa, 0x0

section .text
global main
extern printf
main:
    push rbp
    mov rbp, rsp
    mov rdi, dat
    mov esi, 0xdeedbeef
    call printf
    leave 
    ret
```

gives errno `24` - too many file descriptor opened.

BUT IF CHANGED TO `int 80h`, instead of

```
    leave 
    ret
```

Will terminate **without** error, how's that?

Also, question *number 2:*
If I do not make calling convention by :

```
push rbp
mov rbp, rsp
```

And only `mov rbp, rsp` , without `push`ing `rbp` before, then `command terminated`, although no function was call before, therefore there is no need to push base pointer. So why is it needed (in eyes of compiler), and will terminate?

Comment: What do you mean it "gives" errno 24?  Your code doesn't have any error checking, so where do you see this error reported?  Exactly how do you compile and run this code?

Comment: By the way, one problem with your code is that you don't align the stack to a 16-byte boundary before calling `printf`.  That is required by the ABI, and omitting it is well known to cause crashes in many cases.  I wonder if that is your problem and if you are somehow misinterpreting the error.

Comment: after executed, `echo $?` gives number `24`

Comment: Ah.  That is an exit code, which has nothing to do with errno values.  The exit code is the value returned by `main`, which you would need to put into the `rax` register before returning.  Since you don't, you get the value left in that register by the return from `printf`, which is the number of characters printed: namely 24.

Comment: @NateEldredge I do not know, where did you get it is needed to align program to 16 boundary, however this is not my case, even with that gives that error (and no matter whether align, it does not have any effect anyway, if nasm compiler does not do it for you - I do not know). But the problem is I do not exit from the program. But still there is question, why does `printf` function alocates so many file descriptors? That is root of the problem

Comment: Actually, never mind about the stack alignment - your code happens to do it right in this case.  But it is something to keep in mind should you change it at all.  It's explained in Section 3.2.2 of the [amd64 ABI](https://uclibc.org/docs/psABI-x86_64.pdf)

Comment: Oh, stack alignment is more likely the issue in your question #2.

Comment: But then, If the number returned is number of charactes, then why WILL NOT be returned after `int 80h` as well?

Comment: @NateEldredge about q2, if I make alignment, then I can omit `push rbp`?, but it is still part of calling-convention, so why would alignment suffice to not getting error?

Comment: At the entry point of main, the stack is misaligned by 8, due to the call instruction pushing the return address. There is no need to push rbp if you don’t change it. But there is a need to adjust the stack pointer by 8, and push rbp is a convenient way to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Question 1

**You're mistaken about this having anything to do with file descriptors.  That isn't what's being reported.**

As you explained in comments, 24 is the number shown when you `echo $?` after running the program.  This is the exit code of the program; normally, the value returned from the `main` function or passed to `exit()`.  It can be whatever you want and normally does **not** correspond to an `errno` value.

So why does your program give an exit code of 24?  If `main` returns, then the exit code is its return value.  A function's return value is expected to be left in the `rax` register when it returns (assuming it's of integer or pointer type).  But you never touch the `rax` register, so it still contains the value that was left there when `printf` returns.  Now `printf` returns the number of characters it successfully printed, which for the string you chose is... 24 (count 'em).

It is just a coincidence that 24 also happens to the errno code for "too many open file descriptors" - that is completely unrelated.

If you want to exit with an exit code of 0 to signal success, then you should `xor rax, rax` just before your `ret`.

You didn't show the exact code you used when changing it to `int 0x80` to invoke the `_exit` syscall yourself.  But in that case, the exit code would be whatever is in the `ebx` register when you make the system call.  Maybe your code puts zero in `ebx`, or maybe you are lucky and it happens to already contain zero.

(Side note: `int 0x80` is the interface for 32-bit system calls, and is not appropriate in a 64-bit program which is what you seem to be writing, though it may work in a few cases.  The 64-bit system call interface uses the `syscall` instruction and is explained in A.2.1 of the ABI.)

## Question 2

**You have to align the stack.**

When calling a C function from assembly (as `printf` in this case), you're required by [the x86-64 ABI Section 3.2.2](https://uclibc.org/docs/psABI-x86_64.pdf) to align the stack to a 16-byte boundary.  The stack is aligned appropriately *before* the call to `main`, and the return address pushed by `call` subtracts 8 bytes.

So if you don't touch the stack at all in your code, it will not be correctly aligned when you call `printf`, and this can cause it to crash.  (The assembler will not help you do this; that's not its job.)  But when you push `rbp`, that subtracts a further 8 bytes and gets the stack aligned properly.  So either leave that code in, or align the stack yourself.

And in either case, keep in mind that if you change your code to push more stuff on the stack, you'll have to adjust it accordingly before you make any function calls.

Comment: The specific reason for printf crashing from the ABI violation (misaligned stack) is that the caller also doesn't zero AL, so `printf` dumps the XMM regs to the stack with 16-byte aligned stores.  (To allow for possible `%f` conversions.)  [Segmentation fault on printf - NASM 64bit Linux](//stackoverflow.com/q/25693827)

Comment: Some functions always segfault if you violate the ABI, like scanf in modern glibc.  [glibc scanf Segmentation faults when called from a function that doesn't align RSP](//stackoverflow.com/q/51070716) explains exactly why.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Good find, so that's yet another bug.